# Converting decimal integers to a string representation in an arbitrary base between 2 and 26

Tags: c, memory-management, converting

This code takes an integer and returns a string representing the value in a different base. The value for the base can range between 2 and 26. I have had someone already look over this code and they told me that I was committing a "cardinal sin" of memory management and referred me to the documentation for `malloc()`. I am confused as to what he is referring to. The only thing I have come up with so far is that I do not check to see if memory allocation succeeds when using `calloc()` or `malloc()`. Are there any other things that could or should be improved?

```
char int_to_char(int number){
    if (number > 9) return (char)(((int)'A') + number - 10);
    else return (char)(((int)'0') + number);
}

int change_base(char* output, int buffer_size, int decimal_number, int base){
    //check for valid parameters
    if((base < 2) || (base > 26)) return -1;        //range error

    //ready variables
    int output_i = 0;
    int tmp_string_i = 0;
    int dividend;
    char remainder;
    char * tmp_string = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char));
    memset(output, '\0', buffer_size*sizeof(char));

    //check for negative input
    if(decimal_number < 0){
        output[0] = '-';
        dividend = -decimal_number;
        output_i++;
    }
    else dividend = decimal_number;

    //find digits
    while(dividend / base != 0){
        remainder = int_to_char(dividend % base);
        dividend = dividend / base;
        tmp_string[tmp_string_i] = remainder;
        tmp_string_i++;
        if(tmp_string_i + 1 > buffer_size){     //+1 for the extra negative sign
            free(tmp_string);
            return -2;      //buffer size error
        }
    }
    //add last digit to string
    remainder = int_to_char(dividend);
    tmp_string[tmp_string_i] = remainder;

    //copy tmp_string to output in reverse order
    for(; tmp_string_i >= 0; tmp_string_i--){
        output[output_i] = tmp_string[tmp_string_i];
        output_i++;
    }
    free(tmp_string);
    return 0;
}
```

I have also used this for testing:

```
int main(){
    char * output = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    int ret_val = 0;

    //test cases
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 37, 8);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, -45, 8);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 33945877, 8);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 32, -7);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 37, 4);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 37, 23);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, 37, 2);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 100, -375212123, 26);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    ret_val = change_base(output, 5, -375212123, 26);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output, ret_val);
    char * output2 = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
    ret_val = change_base(output2, 5, 37, 2);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", output2, ret_val);

    free(output);
    free(output2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dividend = -decimal_number;` certainly has trouble when `decimal_number == INT_MIN;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **The cardinal sin**

  An assignment `tmp_string[tmp_string_i] = remainder;` *may* write beyond an allocated memory. Consider a case of `buffer_size` being equal to 0. You must test `tmp_string_i` *before* the assignment. I don't know what exactly *someone* had in mind, but you are definitely committing one.
- **Unnecessary variables**

  `decimal_number` is passed by value; you can mutilate it as much as you want. There is no need to have `dividend`.

  Reversal can be done in-place. There is no need for `tmp_string` at all. `tmp_string_i` shall also be gone.
- **Finding digits**

  Executing division `dividend / base` twice per iteration looks wrong; special-case of the last digit looks also wrong. Using `do-while` solves both wrongs:

  ```
      do {
          output[output_i++] = int_to_char(dividend % base);
          number = number / base;
      } while (number != 0);
  ```
- **No raw loops**

  Most loops represent an important algorithm, which deserves to be factored out in a function of its own, for further reuse *and* for giving it a name. In your case, the loop under the `//copy tmp_string to output in reverse order` comment implements an algorithm known as `reverse`.

All that said, this is

- **Misc**

  - The returned string should be terminated by '\0', or its actual length be returned.
  - The code happily converts numbers to a base up to 36 (10 digits and 26 letters). I see no reason to limit a base to 26.
  - Return codes `0,-1,-2` should be defined as named constants.
  - Size variables (e.g. `buffer_size`) should be unsigned, or better yet of type `size_t`.
  - The `decimal_number` parameter is not *decimal*. It is just *number*. Need to be renamed accordingly.